# Port number of the docker image

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

I am building a PHP+Apache environment using Docker.

I created site.conf and set the VirtualHost port number to 80, it is working without any problems. But if I changed the VirtualHost in site.conf to another port such as 8000, it didn't work and displayed connection refused error message.

Work (VirtualHost *:80 in site.conf)

```
$ docker-compose exec app bash
root@3d0cfdc80ab5:/var/www# curl -l http://localhost:80/phpinfo.php
Displayed the content of the phpinfo() function
```

Didn't work (VirtualHost *:8000 in site.conf)

```
$ docker-compose exec app bash
root@3d0cfdc80ab5:/var/www# curl -l http://localhost:8000/phpinfo.php
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

**site.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>  # change 80 to 8000
    ServerName localhost:8000  # change 80 to 8000
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/cake/

    <Directory /var/www/public_html/cake/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN echo "\n \
log_errors = On\n error_log = /dev/stderr\n error_reporting = E_NOTICE & E_DEPRECATED\n date.timezone = Asia/Tokyo\n " >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN apt-get update -yqq && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends git zip unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/var/www/cake/lib/Cake/Console"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/var/www/cake/app/Vendor/bin"

COPY ./site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY . /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www


RUN mkdir -p tmp/cache/models tmp/cache/persistent && chown -R :www-data tmp && chmod -R 770 tmp

RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart

EXPOSE 8000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8099:8000"
    environment:
      TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "33066:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: cake
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: cake1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testpass1234

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Do I need to set anything other than site.conf, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml to change the VirtualHost port number?

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

I tried with various port numbers and searched for information, but it did not lead to a solution.